# Share upload locations MSM

Tags: multi-site-manager, file-uploads, file-manager, files

Is there a way to share upload locations between MSM sites, or to sync the dirs for both sites?

If not, is there another module that can do this?

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? I can point the upload locations to the same folder for different File Upload Preferences on each site but the file listing goes out of sync. Clicking Synchronize will sync them all but I can't ask the client to do that after every upload.

Comment: unfortunately not...

Answer (score 3):

If you have command line access on the server, you can setup a Symbolic Link:
http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/linking-files-with-symbolic-links-linux-unix-shell-command-tutorial-guides-t479.html

Apparently you can also set up a Symbolic Link without command line access using PHP:  http://perishablepress.com/use-php-to-create-symbolic-links-without-shell-access/